# Keycloak Registration Profile flow

Tags: keycloak

I am experiencing an issue with keycloak quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest where user registration fails with

```
[org.keycloak.services] (executor-thread-23) KC-SERVICES0013: 
Failed authentication: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot 
invoke "org.keycloak.models.UserModel.addRequiredAction(org.keycloak.models.UserModel$RequiredAction)" because "user" is null
```

once i disable the "Registration User Profile Creation" flow. Wondering if I missed something in the configuration or it is broken. Email settings in the real settings are all switched to off.

Answer (score 0):

Which keycloak verison are you using? In case it is 23.0.4, take a look at their [upgrade notes](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/upgrading/index.html#removed-registrationprofile-form-action). Maybe it has something to do with your problem. If not, provide more details please. Show us your registration flow, and if you have any custom FormAction, show is those as well.

> Removed RegistrationProfile form action:
>
> The form action RegistrationProfile (displayed in the UI of authentication flows as Profile Validation) was removed from the codebase and also from all authentication flows. By default, it was in the built-in registration flow of every realm. The validation of user attributes as well as creation of the user including all that user’s attributes is handled by RegistrationUserCreation form action and hence RegistrationProfile is not needed anymore. There is usually no further action needed in relation to this change, unless you used RegistrationProfile class in your own providers.

Comment: It is a brand new docker installation of Keycloak 23.0.4. Zero customizations in any form/flow/etc other than enabling user registration and disabling Registration User Profile Creation in the built-in registration flow. On second thoughts, it might make sense to fail. All I wanted to end up with was to remove first/last names + email. There's another path to first/last name